# how support one service to access multiple company tenants calendar event

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, outlook-addin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds in this document, service could use itself application identity to access customer office365 resource, and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code tell us how to let one backend service to support on-behalf-of cases to visit users office 365 resource, i want to know how could support both scenarios in one backend service.

by the way, the frontend is office 365 outlook addin

thanks.

Comment: Please explain more about your requirement . Which scenario you are facing ?

Comment: hi Nan Yu, sorry for didn't describe my question clearly. In our outlook add-in production, we have two scenarios need to be supported,  the first is that if customer admin consent the permission to our add-in service app, our service app could get users calendar information by itself app access token without other end user in the same domain to consent again, our add-in service could show the information in the outlook add-in client.

Comment: The second is that if admin didn't consent the permission to our add-in service, add-in service could ask the normal end user to consent, and add-in service could on-behalf-of the user to access himself calendar resource. I want to know how i can implement this based on the MSFT apis. Not sure whether you get my question, any problem pls let me know. thanks much.